# Adding Close functionality for mobile menu with submenu

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, mobile, menu

I'm working on a mobile menu for a website I built in Wordpress + Divi Theme.
When the website user clicks on a "hamburgericon" it opens a fullscreen menu:

mobile menu

[image]

When you tap "Termine" it opens up a submenu:

mobile menu with submenu

[image]

I would like the submenu to vanish again, when tapping "termine" for the second time. But I sadly don't know how.

Here is the code I worked with:

```
<li class="nav-link">
    <a href="#">Termine<i class="fas fa-caret-fown"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown_link">
                    <a href="#" onclick="closeNav()">Regelmäßige Termine</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown_link">
                    <a href="#" onclick="closeNav()">Besondere Termine</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown_link">
                    <a href="#" onclick="closeNav()">Freizeiten</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</li>
```

The CSS for opening the submenu looks like this:

```
.nav-link:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
 }
```

The Java script function for "closeNav()" is:

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}
```

Please note the following:

- If the `<a>` elements are regular HTML links (not generated by some  javascript router), when the user clicks them, they will just navigate to a different page, so the menu will close either way.
- Your page looks like it is intended for mobile usage. In most mobile devices, `hover` will not work since tapping the link is actually a click.

Comment: Hey thank you for your comment! This is just for making the Nav vanish, when clicking on <a> right? Do you also have a solution for the main problem? Thank you =)

Comment: @johnthreesixteenamen yes, it should disappear when an element is clicked.

Comment: Great thanks! Do you know how to solve my main problem? That, when i click on the dropdown-trigger "Termine" the second time, it makes the dropdown submenu dissapear? Thank you

Comment: @johnthreesixteenamen I created this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/anpel13/2cqku3h7/. In chrome mobile, it does not disappear on subsequent clicks. Once again, using `:hover` when you basically mean `expanded`, is not an ideal solution, and may end up having unexpected results.